# Trying to focus an already opened popup window from a new page

Tags: javascript, popup

I have two pages, page "a" and page "b".

Page'a" generates a js popup window by

```
function loadWindow(){
var params = 'status = 0, height = 300, width = 480, resizable = 0';
if(isTouchDevice()){
    params = ''
}
w = window.open('/audio/audioplayer.php?id='+audioId, 'audioplayer', params);
w.document.close();
}
```

A visitor then goes to page b (popup window is still open). I would like a button on page b, when pressed it brings focus to the popup which was created on page a.

I have tried searching for the answer yet nothing works. I understand I can bring focus with

```
window.open('', 'audioplayer', '');
```

or

```
w.focus();
```

but the problem is I can't figure out how to reference the popup from page "a"

Comment: Why doesn't `var w = window.open('', 'audioplayer', ''); w.focus();` work? The fact that you're using the same second parameter (the name of the window) means you should be able to grab a handle on the popup that way

Comment: How is it that you're keeping a popup window open while loading a new page?

Comment: @isherwood What do you mean? If you open a popup with `window.open`, then navigate to another page in a few seconds, the popup stays open.

Comment: Ok. Don't think I've ever witnessed that happening.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the other window, because your reference dies when you go to page b. Most browsers won't allow this - for security reasons. If this was possible any page to access all your browser tabs.

You can test this. By openining the pop up, then execute window.opener within it. This will return page a. But when you browse to page b from page a. The pop up's window's opener property will be null.

**A work around** would be to dynamicly load page b into page a. That way the window and reference will be preserved.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I assumed, hoping I was wrong... 

Is their such a way to save the reference inside a cookie or something?

Comment: Not that i know of. You can convert it to json and recreate an object like it. But never the same object - because it is dead as it has no references. Which will not have a reference to the old window. I'm sorry, I think an iframe or dynamicly loading page b is your best option.